# mySQL outer join

Tags: mysql, join, outer-join

I have 2 tables for which I need to run a query on

> Table1 has 2 fields: l_id, and name
>
> Table2 also has 2 fields:   l_id, and b_id

I need to run a query to get the "name" and "l_id" for all the entries in table1 that do not have an entry in table2 for a given b_id.

Hope this makes some sense

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
select t1.*
from Table1 t1
left outer join Table2 t2 on t1.l_id = t2.l_id
    and t2.b_id = @SomeValue
where t2.l_id is null
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use an outer join, but I find a sub-query is a little more straightforward. In your case selecting everything from table1 that does not have an id in table2. Reads better...

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE l_id NOT IN (SELECT l_id FROM table2);
```

Comment: this works for me, I just modified that second query to add the b_id condition, but to be fair, RedFilter answered first

Comment: No worries. I missed the b_id part anyway.